# How to do a proper way to copy URL->bstrVal to a global variable?

Tags: visual-c++

I have this function inside my program:

```
void CBar::NavigateComplete2(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *URL)
  {

try {
    UpdateBar(UpdateNavigateComplete);
} catch (...) {
    ASSERT(0);
}
  }
```

I need to have the URL value from `URL->bstrVal` from this function and to copy it to a global variable so that my other function can easily refer to it.

What is the appropriate way to do this? since my current method destroys the stability of my program..it crash all the time.

Comment: You may want to explain you current architecture a little better. Using global variables only rarely is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question or the motivation. If all you want to do is, as described in the question, copy the value of `URL->bstrVal` then the simplest way to to use a wrapper `BSTR` class for the global.

```
namespace { // keep global private to .cpp file
    CComBSTR globalURL;
}

void CBar::NavigateComplete2(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *URL)
{
    if (URL != NULL && URL->vt == VT_BSTR)
        globalURL = URL->bstrVal;
```

Otherwise you should use a raw `BSTR` and copy it with [`SysAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) (and don't forget to `SysFreeString` it when you're done with the global.

If you don't copy the string (and only copy the pointer) the `VARIANT`'s owner will destroy it giving you a global with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Can i assign the 'global' to a std::wstring currentUrl  ? So that my 'currentUrl' will have the value from 'global'.

Comment: @karikari, yes since a `BSTR` is only a `wchar_t*` (with different semantics) you can copy it into a `std::wstring` since the `wstring` will copy the string and not just the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use SysAllocString(URL->bstrVal) to create a copy off the BSTRVAL. you will have to free it when you're done with it using SysFreeString().

Though I have to agree with @Space_C0wb0y that using global varsity for this is error prone. Unless UpdateBar does something asynchronously, you should just pass URL->bstrVal as a parameter to it. And even if UpdateBar schedules asynchronous work, it should still encapsulate creating the BSTR copy and associating it with the asynchronous work, to avoid race between the background code and another NavigateComplete event both trying to access the global var. (Or you have to lock the access to it, which pretty much negates the asynchronous idea, unless you know how to optimize your locks really well)